# Java Script in Validation controls in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Can i give alert message box of javascript in errormessage property of required field validator in asp.net

Answer (score 0):

This reference page : [ASP.Net Message Box Alert Display](http://forums.asp.net/t/1461308.aspx) shows some help regarding how to show alert message using ASP.net.

I don't know weather this will solve your problem or not as this is not case of RequireFieldValidator. Correct me if I am wrong.

Thanking You.